# inputing [ 0 10 20 40 ] for exemple as argument for array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know there are other ways, for example :

```
from array import *
arr = array("i", list(map(int, input("Give an array : ").split())))
```

I am not using Numpy library but if there is a way to do this, it will be helpful.

The Output I am looking for is (In the Console):

```
Array1: [ 0 10 20 40 60]
Array2: [10, 40]
Common values between two arrays are:
[10 40]
```

I know the code for comparision but the one i don't kno is how to define an array from inputing this :
[ 0 10 20 40 60]

Comment: You're two characters away from the goal. You just need to remove the brackets from the input - the first and the last characters.

Comment: You're better add some checks for the input. After that, just use `set` to compare the intersection between the two lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this helps?  (then you can do Array2 and set() operation as earlier posts suggested).

```py
    >>> Array1 = [int(x) for x in input('Enter a few numbers to creat Array: ').split()]
    Enter a few numbers to creat Array: 0 10 20 40 60
    >>> Array1
    [0, 10, 20, 40, 60]
```